# Forcing the generated bitmaps to be used on API 21 and above instead of vector drawables

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bitmap

As you know Android Studio build pipeline generates bitmap versions of vector drawables to be used on devices prior to API 21.
As some of our vectors are larger than the suggested resolution of 200dpx200dp, their draw performance as vector drawable is not very good.
We don't want to stop using vector drawables on our design process but we don't want the vector files to be included in our apk as well. Instead we want the bitmap version to be used on devices above API 21.
Is something like that possible?

Comment: You can do a simple if/else and check if the device is pre-lollipop or not then set them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Proguard to do that -> https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#keep-resources

it may need a little bit of configuring though. All the best!

**New Edit:**
Please try the following:

Create an XML file in your project with a  tag and specify each resource to keep in the tools:keep attribute and each resource to discard in the tools:discard attribute

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:keep="@drawable/bitmap_used*_c,@drawable/bitmap_used_a,@drawable/bitmap_used_b*"
tools:discard="@@drawable/vector_unused2" />
```

I have tried it. It works. Let me know how it goes for you.

Comment: Could you be more specific please? I couldn't find a way to do that with proguard.

Comment: I've no bitmaps on my project, they are generated automatically by the build pipeline. So it's not possible to distinguish between bitmap outputs and original vector drawables this way.

Comment: Are you just trying to decrease the app size? Or is there a bigger issue that you are tackling which has not been explained here? There are several easier ways to decrease app sizes. Do and try and elaborate a little more about the problem you are solving.